# How can I check for an ignored UILocalNotification?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to figure out a way to know which notifications have been ignored/missed while the app was not running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the solutions I came up with is...

1. Store the date/time in userinfo parameter and also save this in a database.
2. After receiving a notification, check the userinfo and remove from database.
3. At startup, get all stored notification info and if any date/time is earlier than today, those have been missed / not handled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this will work if the notification repeat interval is not set...what if the repeat interval is set to something say daily...how do i check the ignored uilocalnotification which appeared due to repeat interval??

Answer (score 0):

`UIApplication` has the method `-scheduledLocalNotifications`. Should do the trick. If unsure whether it was checked or not, use the userInfo to identify the notifications, and persist that info with either NSUserDefaults, a database, or any other form of persistency.